# apply permissions to uploaded sharepoint documents programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, sharepoint-2010

i'm developing an interface to retrieve a file from sharepoint.  i have the following method to upload a document:

```
    public bool UploadDocument(string document)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetFullPath(document)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var site = GetNewDataContext(SiteUrl);
        try
        {
            using (var clientContext = GetNewContext())
            {
                var uploadLocation = string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", SiteUrl, Helpers.ListNames.RequestedDocuments, Path.GetFileName(document));

                //Get Document List
                var documentslist = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Helpers.ListNames.RequestedDocuments);

                var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation
                {
                    Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(document), //Assign to content byte[] i.e. documentStream
                    Overwrite = true, //Allow owerwrite of document
                    Url = uploadLocation //Upload URL
                };

                var uploadFile = documentslist.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);

                uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            site.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict, true);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(exception.Message);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

However, my next step is to apply a custom permission.. i've found some blogs online which demonstrate how to do this:
http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/10/programmatically-add-delete-modify-item.html

- Is it possible to set the permission in the uploading process?
- my understanding is, when the file is uploaded it inherits permissions from the list its uploaded to.
- my current download method returns a ListItem.. Is it possible to cast a ListItem to SPListItem?  The reason for returning a SpListItem is due to the blog i posted above.. it appears SPListItem contains the permission info i need [to break and apply the new permission to].

my download method returns a ListItem.. how can i do this as an SPListItem

```
    private static ListItemCollection GetListItemCollectionFromSp(string documentListName, string name, string value, string type, int rowLimit)
    {
        ListItemCollection listItems = null;
        using (var ctx = GetNewContext())
        {
            var documentsList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentListName);

            var camlQuery = new CamlQuery
            {
                ViewXml =
                    @"<View>

                    <Query>
                        <Where>

                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='" + name + @"'/>

                                <Value Type='" + type + "'>" + value + @"</Value>
                            </Eq>

                        </Where>
                        <RowLimit>" + rowLimit + @"</RowLimit>

                    </Query>
                </View>"
            };

            listItems = documentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            ctx.Load(documentsList);

            ctx.Load(listItems,
                items => items.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
                item => item.DisplayName));

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        return listItems;
    }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to configure item level permissions in document library. Correct me if I am wrong.

Firstly, You have to stop inheriting permissions from parent site. You can then create a workflow and let it trigger when a document is uploaded. It is easy to design a workflow to configure permissions on item level than doing it in code. Maintenance would be easy too.